# $f: \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ so that it maps $X$-axis to the graph of $y=|x|$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, continuity

How to prove whether there does exist a differentiable map $f: \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ so that it maps the $X$-axis to the $ S = \{ (x, y): y=|x| \}$?

For example, i got an attempt to build something, which should looks like an example: 
$f(x) = \begin{cases} x &\mbox{if } |x|>\frac{1}{n} \\ 
x^{2}+\frac{n-1}{n^{2}}& \mbox{if } |x| \le \frac{1}{n} \end{cases} $
Does this seem to be an appropriate one?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your function is a function of one variable, it has to be two variables, so something like $f(x,y)$ and it has  to have two variables in the range to.  So something like $f(x,y)=(x^2y,x+y)$ - not that that works, but it's an example  of a function from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $s(x) = -1, x < 0, s(0)=0, s(x) = 1, x> 0.$ Define

$$g(x) = e^{-1/x^2}, x\ne 0,\,\, g(0) = 0.$$

Then both $g(x), s(x)g(x) \in C^\infty(\mathbb {R}).$ The map $f(x,y) = (s(x)g(x),g(x))$ is therefore in $C^\infty(\mathbb {R}^2)$ (hence is differentiable on $\mathbb {R}^2)$ and maps the $x$-axis into $\{(x,|x|):x\in \mathbb {R}\}.$ If we need $f$ to take the $x$-axis onto $\{(x,|x|):x\in \mathbb {R}\},$ then we can easily modify this example.